# Combining raster images?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster

I've decided to work on GIS implementation in transportation.

I've these small tiles of images, with world files.

I want to combine them to create a base map.

I don't know coding/programming, so please suggest some other other method to combine these tiles.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! You will find people here most willing to help when your question (which you can edit to improve at any time) includes details of what you have researched/tried so far.  My recommendation would be to review this set of [existing Q&As](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mosaic+arcgis-desktop) to see if any of them already provide the answer that you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Mosaic to New Raster (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000098000000) tool.

That is probably the easiest way of merging two or more rasters, just make sure that you specify the appropriate resampling technique for the type of data your raster represents, the tool help will help you decide which technique to use.

You will also want to specify the mosaic operator, which determines how the portions of each raster which overlap are handled.